# Select a table row base on the content of a custom attribute

Tags: jquery

So I have a table with multiple rows. the first TD of each row content a custom attribute tag called lineup. Ex:

```
<td lineup="['463', '442', '200', '97', '238', '548', '166', '184', '353', '26', '573']">Some stuff</td>
```

This is actually a list I pass into the html through Jinja2. I figured it was the best solution to store this data. Maybe I'm wrong, I'm just starting to code.

Now what I want to do is select the row when the lineup contain a specific ID.

Right now I'm doing it like so:

```
$("#xtable tbody td[lineup*='"+ID+"'']").parent()
```

Which work great except if the ID is 63, it will also select the row with the id 463. I understand why it is doing this since it's basically searching a string, he doesn't know that 463 is actually not 63.

So my questions:

- Is there a better way to store the data in the html / js ?
- Using regex ( which I don't know how to use ) can I make it find only
  63 and not 463 for example?

**EDIT:**

This is my Jquery function:

```
$('#update li').hover(function(){
        playerId = $(this).find('span').attr("pid");
        $("#xtable tbody td[lineup*='"+playerId+"'']").parent().css("background-color","#d9edf7")
        },
        function(){
            $("#xtable tbody td[lineup*='"+playerId+"'']").parent().css("background-color","")
});
```

Example of a li element to get the playedId

```
<li class="pushmsg" style=""><p><span rel="tooltip" class="player-name" pid="14" data-original-title="total point: 3">Arshavin</span> just got an assist</p></li>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be to include the apostrophes in the string that you filter for. You should prepend it with a backslash, as you want it to be seen as a string.

```
$("#xtable tbody td[lineup*='\'"+ID+"\'']").parent()
```

I would recommend you against custom attributes as much as possible, but if you do need them, use a data-* attribute. More information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#custom-data-attribute) and [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/). With data-lineup, your code would look like this:

```
$("#xtable tbody td[data-lineup*='\'"+ID+"\'']").parent()
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. Also thank you for the data- tips. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove asterisk `*`

```
 $("#xtable tbody td[lineup='"+ID.toString()+"'']").parent()
```

Comment: If I remove the asterisk, it doesn't find anything since my list is not a string.

Comment: `my list is now a string` do you mean anything inside `lineup` is string?

Comment: God damn typos. What I wanted to say was that the list I pass from jinja is string inside `lineup`.

Comment: still not working. I have updated my original question with more code to show you what I'm actually doing.

Comment: why are you using `''` at the end of `#xtable tbody td[lineup*='"+playerId+"` just before `]`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#xtable tbody td[lineup*="\''+ID+'\'"]').parent()
```

Included the single quotes around your IDs in the attribute substring to match, but escaped.

Also: you win the award for awkwardness.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GHmjr/